# Print the values of (3^i *7^j) in increasing order and in optimal way

Tags: algorithm, loops, dynamic-programming

I encountered an interview questions which asks you to print the value of `3i * 7j` in increasing order but in optimal way.e.g.

> `30 * 70 = 1` 
>   `31 * 70 = 3` 
>   `30 * 71 = 7` 
>   `32 * 70 = 9` 
>   `31 * 71 = 21` 
>   `33 * 70 = 27`

and so on ...

Comment: (Yes, the prime factors are different. BFD.)

Comment: JavaScript attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/groovy/TYUBR/

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29). Start by inserting the smallest value (`3^0 * 7^0`). At each step, print the minimum (this will be the root of your heap), remove it, and add `3 * minimum` and `7 * minimum` to the heap.

This has `O(log n)` time complexity.

Comment: But "at each step" makes O(n)?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik - it is `O(log n)` to find what the next value you should print is, where `n` is however many values you want to print.

Answer (score 0):

```
A(i,j)=3^i * 7^j
when i != 0 and j != 0:
    A(i,j)=A(i-1,j-1)*21
when i!=0 and j==0:
    A(i,0)=A(i-1,0)*3
when i==0 and j!=0:
    A(0,j)=A(0,j-1)*7
when i==0 and j==0:
    A(0,0)=1
```

You can store the them into a 2-D array, such that you can get the former value from it.

Comment: You are missing the major point , you should print it in increasing order , how it is helpful there?

Answer (score 0):

the only thing i can think of when you say optimal is to calculate it and save in a table the values. then calculate only the multiplication

```
     long[] threePower = new long[10];
     long[] sevenPower = new long[10];

     threePower[0] = sevenPower[0] = 1;
     for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
     {
        threePower[i] = threePower[i - 1]*3;
        sevenPower[i] = sevenPower[i - 1] * 7;
     }
```

and then print the combinations

Comment: How will you efficiently print them in increasing order?

Comment: @IVlad in a double for statement

Comment: That would be `O(n^2)` - not very efficient.

Comment: @IVlad you are saying this is O(n^2), what is the n here? the amount of multiplication?, because you are doing the same i believe... when you are saying something on efficiency you have to explain in what are you measuring it

Comment: `n` is the amount of values you are asked to print. The problem doesn't even state that this is given, and your algorithm assumes that it is. Even if you generate enough values, you still haven't explained anything past "print the combinations" - you have to print them in sorted order. Do you just sort them? That's `O(n^2 log n)`.